# Parse iOS Objective C throws IndexNotFound when using whereKey:matchesText:

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, parse-server

I've been trying to use Parse's built in text feature, where I want to search for users that have a username similar to the string *query*. When I try to run the code I get and *IndexNotFound* error, although text indexes are automatically created. I don't know what I'm missing, since what's shown in the Parse iOS Developers Guide is pretty much the same as what I've written here.
Parse iOS Developers Guide: https://docs.parseplatform.org/ios/guide/#queries-on-string-values

```
PFQuery *accountQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"_User"];
[accountQuery whereKey:@"username" matchesText:query];
    
[accountQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *accounts, NSError *error)  {
    if (accounts) {
         self.accounts = accounts;
         [self.tableView reloadData];
     }
     else {
          NSLog(@"Error fetching accounts: %@", error);
     }
}];
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
[Error]: { 
   "$clusterTime" =     {
    clusterTime = 6855442277490229249;
    signature =         {
        hash = "5uhLQNEDbXXCs24ZuWTIkptlP3g=";
        keyId = 6829485114355875841;
    };
};
code = 27;
codeName = IndexNotFound;
errmsg = "text index required for $text query";
name = MongoError;
ok = 0;
operationTime = 6855442277490229249;
} (Code: 1, Version: 1.18.0)
```

Comment: `if (accounts)` or `if (!error)` so you are printing the error object when accounts == nil

Comment: @OlSen there's no edit and OP has `if (accounts)` there, no idea what do you mean with this comment.

Comment: @Zurken Google & 2nd result -> [Indexes are not automatically created when using fullText on User field](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/5084) -> _At this time we don’t provide index creation on the fly for those. Please refer to mongo Db driver documentations to create such indexes._ -> `db.getCollection("_User").createIndex({myField: "text"})`

Comment: my comment means.. when there is an error but `accounts!=nil` it will not print an error apart from debugger does it if it breaks. So the error shown above can be the normal content when no result is found even if it worked. Instead it should check `if (error!=nil)` and then go for `accounts`

Answer (score 1):

As @zrzka pointed out in the comment, you need to create an index in your `User` class:

```
db.getCollection("_User").createIndex({username: "text"})
```

But I need to point out that MongoDB does not support partial text search. For example, if you have a username called `"awesomename"`, and your query string is `"name"`, you won't get anything back.

But if the username has a white space in it: `"awesome name"`, a query with search string "name" will give you this user.

[MongoDB Text Search](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/text-search/) explains pretty well.

However if you do want to perform a partial search, please use regex. Detail can be found [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/).

And here's an example of an regex search in Swift:

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "_User")  
query.whereKey("display_name", matchesRegex: "na", modifiers: "i")
// will match anything that contains "na", and "i" modifier means case insensitive
query.findObjectsInBackground { (objects: [PFObject]?, error: Error?) in
    if let error = error {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    } else if let objects = objects {
        print("found \(objects.count) users")
        objects.forEach { (object) in
            print("User \(object.objectId!)");
        }
    }
}
```